# FQDN on Windows7 Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, azure

I have a Windows 7 Virtual Machine hosted on Azure with this public IP  *mymachinename.resourceplace.cloudapp.azure.com* given by Azure portal. 
I use this address to connect with my machine through Windows Remote Desktop.

Now I ask you if there is a way (or a command) to know this string from inside the virtual machine itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get FQDN directly inside the VM.

**FQDN is just a DNS name to point to the VM resource.** It will work for any port you desire, once the appropriate Network Security Group rules are then created to allow the respective traffic to reach your VM.

However, you could use Azure PowerShell to get FQDN.

```
$ip=Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName <group name> -Name <Public IP address name>
$fqdn=$ip.DnsSettings.Fqdn
$fqdn
```

This is my test result.

[image]

Comment: I have read the [Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.network/v3.0.0/get-azurermpublicipaddress) but when I run `$ip=Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName myRemote -Name myRemote` (yes, both the Resource Group Name and Virtual Machine has the same name) the PowerShell returns this error: `Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress : The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/myRemote' under resource group 'myRemote' was not found.
StatusCode: 404
ReasonPhrase: Not Found `

Comment: Hi, please ensure your Public IP name is correct. According to your issue. It seems your public IP is not correct or existing.

Comment: You could try to use `Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName myRemote` to get Public IP name

Comment: I have found the mistake: I have used the Virtual Machine name instead of the public IP name (which in my case is "myRemote-ip").
With command `$ip=Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName myRemote -Name myRemote-ip` it works properly.